# How to correctly call a 2D array from another method in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I am trying to create an object and calling it via the main method/ a constructor. When I print it out I get a list but I needed it printed out like a table. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test2 {
    public static String[][] makeTable(int mouseLocationRow, int mouseLocationColumn) {
        int rows = 12;
        int columns = 12;
        String[][] a = new String[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                a[i][j] =   "#";
            }
        }
        a[mouseLocationRow][mouseLocationColumn] = "&";
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 5;
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(makeTable(a, b)));
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

```
[[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, &, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]]
```

Here is how its supposed to look like:

```
############
############
############
############
############
#####&######
############
############
############
############
############
############
```

How do I make my output look like how its supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use char[][] instead of String[][]..

Then, to display, use something like printTable() below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test2 {
    public static char[][] makeTable(int mouseLocationRow, int mouseLocationColumn) {
        int rows = 12;
        int columns = 12;
        char[][] table = new char[rows][columns];

        for (char[] row : table)
            Arrays.fill(row, '#');

        table[mouseLocationRow][mouseLocationColumn] = '&';
        return table;
    }

    public static void printTable(char[][] table) {
        for (char[] row : table)
            System.out.println(new String(row));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 5;
        printTable(makeTable(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason I used a string was because # is a string and won't let me use a char[][], it says type mismatch cant convert from a string to a char. How do I make it so that the char[][] takes # as an input?

Comment: you have to use `'#'` instead of `"#"` (single quotes for chars, double quotes for strings)

Comment: oh I fixed it maybe I used the ascii code for # and it worked. Testing out full code now.

Comment: Ok I wasn't able to get it working, where would I put that code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like :

```
 public void print2DArray(int[][] arr) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And Call it from your main method like this:

```
    int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    print2DArray(arr);
```

Or did i miss something ?